# RavenDB Include - Session.Load<T>(string[] ids)

Tags: ravendb

Is there a reason why I can't perform an Include to include a collection of documents from a query, then load them all in one query, rather than using a for-loop.

```
var messages = Session.Query<MessageRecipient, MessageInboxIndex>()
                .Include(x => x.MessageId)
                .ToList();

Session.Load<Message>(messages.Select(x => x.MessageId));
```

This seems to go back to the database to fetch the objects rather than use the cache...is this by design or can it be fixed?

Paul

Comment: Are you running RavenDB in Client/Server mode or Embedded?

Comment: Also what do you `MessageRecipient` docs look like and what's the code for the `MessageInboxIndex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul, I just submitted a pull-request for that. I guess you will find this in one of the upcoming builds.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Just out of interest where can I see what was modified in ravendb to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Paul,
That is because the optimization isn't implemented, that is all.
A pull request for that would be appreciated.