# In RavenDB, how to query for nested "objects" in the document?

Tags: c#, database, nosql, ravendb

If I have stored documents which look like this:

```
Category {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public List<Category> Categories {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Essentially a category, with sub-categories. In my case, only ever 2 levels deep (1 parent, n sub-categories).

Querying for all categories works great, showing a nice list (with nested sub-category lists too). My users can only click a sub-category, to view things within selected category. I want to pull 1 of the sub-categories out, as a `Category`.

Given a sub-category Id, how would I pull one of the sub-categories out as it's own stand-alone `Category`?

**Update**

I'd like to add, I am getting around this by doing this:

```
        Category pCat = RavenSession.Query<Category>().Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();
        Category cat = pCat.Categories.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which first gets the category which contains the sub-category, then queries the sub-categories on that category to pull the specific sub-category.

Perhaps this is better, I don't know... but seems like it's doing 2 steps when 1 could suffice.

**Update 2**

All id's in these categories are manually added, no RavenDB auto id's (even the sub-categories have an Id).

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to get a Category given a Sub-Category Id?

Answer (score 2):

Your *Categories* property holds a list of object, where instead you can have the ids of the nested categories.  The child categories, the way you have it built, will not have ids, only data.

```
Category {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public List<Category> Categories {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Instead try this model and this query:

```
Category {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public List<string> CategoryIDs {get;set;}
    ...
}

var parent = session
    .Include(i => i.CategoryIDs)
    .Load<Category>("category/1");

var children= session.Load<Category>(parent.CategoryIDs);
```

A caveat: I haven't tested this code since I don't have a project to test it in right now, but here are my sources:

1. http://ayende.com/blog/4584/ravendb-includes
2. [RavenDB Include - Session.Load<T>(string[] ids)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049408/ravendb-include-session-loadtstring-ids)
3. http://richarddingwall.name/2012/03/08/ravendb-includes-much-simpler-than-you-think/

Comment: It took me a while to grok what you were saying... but I think what you're trying to say is that the sub-categories would have no id's because RavenDB wouldn't auto-create the nested document ids.

In my case, the id's are all manually assigned id's, and all the sub-categories have id's as well.

I'm sorry, I didn't think to have that in my question, I'll add it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not so much that they don't have IDs but that they are not documents. Raven doesn't know about them independently from the parent category.  When you request a data from Raven, you're either requesting a document (by ID or query) or a reduce result (by reduce index.)  The only way to get the data you're looking for is by either making all categories documents, creating your own reduce index (which may be difficult for your nesting), or doing exactly what you're doing (pulling the parent document and LINQing for the rest.)